# C++ vector.erase() function bug

Tags: c++, vector, element

I have this vector:

```
list.push_back("one");
list.push_back("two");
list.push_back("three");
```

I use `list.erase(list.begin() + 1)` to delete the "two" and it works. But when I try to output the list again:

```
cout<<list[0]<<endl;
cout<<list[1]<<endl;
cout<<list[2]<<endl;
```

produces:

```
one
three
three
```

I tried targeting the last element for erasing with list.erase(list.begin() + 2), but the duplicate three's remain. I imagined index 2 should have been shifted and list[2] should have outputted nothing. list[3] outputs nothing, as it should.

I'm trying to erase the "two" and output the list as only:

```
one
three
```

Comment: You are accessing `list[2]` after having erased it, which is undefined behaviour.  Try `.at(2)` instead and you'll get an `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: So it did work, and I'm just accessing something that doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: In typical implementations, to save time, memory doesn't get erased. It's just marked unused and the system carries the old value on until the memory is needed again and the value is over written.

Comment: @EtiennePierre-Jerome More precisely, you are accessing something that need not exist anymore.

Comment: This would be a good time to learn about the range based for loop!

Answer (score 3):

When using `cout<<list[2]<<endl;` you asume that you still have three elements. But in fact you are accessing remaining data in a part of the memory that is no more used.

You should use `list.size ()` to obtain the number of elements. So, something like:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < list.size (); i++ )
{
    cout<<list[i]<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But you erased the element, thus the size of your container was decreased by one, i.e. from 3 to 2.

So, after the erase, you shouldn't do this:

```
cout<<list[0]<<endl;
cout<<list[1]<<endl;
cout<<list[2]<<endl; // Undefined Behaviour!!
```

but this:

```
cout<<list[0]<<endl;
cout<<list[1]<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the "three" is just copied to the index 1, which is expected. you is vector.size() == 2 now.

it is because vector will do pre-allocation, which help to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

To keep from having to resize with every change, vector grabs a block of memory bigger than it needs and keeps it until forced to get bigger or instructed to get smaller.

To brutally simplify, think of it as

```
string * array = new string[100];
int capacity = 100
int size = 0;
```

In this case you can write all through that 100 element array without the program crashing because it is good and valid memory, but only values beneath `size` have been initialized and are meaningful. What happens when you read above `size` is undefined. Because reading out of bounds is a bad idea and preventing it has a performance cost that should not be paid by correct usage, the C++ standard didn't waste any time defining what the penalty for doing so is. Some debug or security critical versions will test and throw exceptions or mark unused portions with a [canary value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Stack_canaries) to assist in detecting faults, but most implementations are aiming for maximum speed and do nothing.

Now you push_back "one", "two", and "three". The array is still 100 elements, `capacity` is still 100, but `size` is now 3.

You erase `array[1]` and every element after 1 up to size will be copied up one element (note potentially huge performance cost here. `vector` is not the right data structure choice if you are adding and removing items from it at random locations)  and `size` will be reduced by one resulting in "one", "three", and "three". The array is still 100 elements, `capacity` is still 100, but `size` is now 2.

Say you add another 99 strings. This pushes `size` each time a string is added and when `size` will exceed `capacity`, a new array will be made, the old array will be copied to the new, and the old will be freed. Something along the lines of:

```
capacity *= 1.5;
string * temp = new string[capacity];
for (int index = 0; index < size; index ++)
{
    temp[index] = array[index];
}
delete array;
array = temp;
```

The array is now 150 elements, `capacity` is now 150, and `size` is now 101.

Result:

There is usually a bit of fluff around the end of a vector that will allow reading out of bounds without the program crashing, but do not confuse this with the program working.